# Spark with Play!: how to remove warn "Can not initialize counter due to context is not a instance of TaskInputOutputContext"?

Tags: apache-spark, playframework

In my Play! 2.5 application using Spark 2.0.0, I get a lot of warnings saying:

```
[WARN ] o.a.p.h.ParquetRecordReader: Can not initialize counter due to context is not a instance of TaskInputOutputContext, but is org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.TaskAttemptContextImpl
```

I don't understand it and it doesn't seem to be problematic. Can I safely ignore them? If yes, how can I disable the logs?

Comment: Same problem here, but without the Framework :-) Any idea on how you countered this issue?

Comment: No sorry, I never found any way to counter this issue